# Is it possible to get the Line Number of an Element in AngleSharp?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I am putting together a map of all the inline styles on elements in a large project. I would like to show the line number where they are located similar the example below.

Is it possible to get the line number of an element in AngleSharp?

```
        foreach (var file in allFiles)
        {
            string source = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);

            var parser = new HtmlParser();
            var doc = parser.ParseDocument(source);
            var items = doc.QuerySelectorAll("*[style]");

            sb.AppendLine($"{file.Name} - inline styles({items.Count()})");

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"\t\tstyle (**{item.LineNumber}**): {item.GetAttribute("style")}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Quick example:

```
var parser = new HtmlParser(new HtmlParserOptions
{
    IsKeepingSourceReferences = true,
});
var document = parser.ParseDocument("<html><head></head><body><a href=\"example.com/?h=4&w=8\">&foo</a></body></html>");
document.QuerySelector("body").SourceReference?.Position.Dump();
```

The output looks as follows:

[image]

The important part is to use the `IsKeepingSourceReferences` option, as this will allow you to use `SourceReference`. Some (by the parser / spec inserted) elements may not have a source reference, so keep in mind that this may be `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Let me take a look at that

Comment: I do not see IsKeepingSourceReferences on:  "new CssParser(new CssParserOptions() )". I take it that you can not get the line number when parsing stylesheets using AngleSharp.css?

Comment: Sounds like a great feature request!

Comment: I'll consider doing that!